# Convert time from Excel in number format to a time or date format in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

When I read a cell in Excel that has a time value, the cell which could say 12:45 PM reads as 5.89 when using a library like XlsxWriter. How do I convert 5.89 into a time object that I can utilize?

Edit: I'm a confirmed idiot--I was reading the wrong cell values which contained floats. The values for time came out perfectly as 12:45:00 which I will most likely just convert using datetime.

Comment: can you share a example of your xls ?

Comment: Side note: Excel's "time values" are just numbers, specifically fractions of 1. `12:45 PM` is `0.53125`, or `12.75/24`.